# fetch the lookup id of user object in apex

Tags: apex, user

I have a hierachrical field on **user** object, I want to fetch the value inside apex  to send mails. but i am getting:

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field

```
User u = [select id, Email, Name from user LIMIT 10];
User u1 =[select id, Name, Manager__r.id from user where Id  =:u.Manager__r.id];
Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
sendTo.add(u.Id);
sendTo.add(u1.Manager__r.Id);
```

The soql query works in developer console but not in apex. How can I fetch in apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not query the `Managerid` in your first SOQL, hence the error.

Replace the following

```
User u = [select id, Email, Name from user LIMIT 10];
```

With this

```
User u = [select id, Email, Manager__c Name from user LIMIT 10];
```

> **Efficiency check**

On the efficiency grounds, you have not fully mentioned your requirements, but you could use something like the code given below to make your stuff more readable and better:

```
User userwithManger = [select id, Email, Name, Manager__c from user LIMIT 10];
// You dont need to use the following soql. User with his/her manager id could be retrieved using single soql. more effcient.
// User u1 =[select id, Name, Manager__r.id from user where Id  =:u.Manager__r.id];
Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
sendTo.add(userwithManger.Id);  // id of the user
sendTo.add(userwithManger.Manager__c); // id of the manager
```

P.S. I don't understand why are you adding `Id` to the `sendTo` list, I think it should have been `email` but may be you have some other requirement. Secondly, `Manager` is out-of-the-box standard User field. `Manager__r` means you have implemented a custom field. So the above solution is as per your requirement mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..wat im trying to do is to send emails to user based on the user hierachry...  1)sql query User u = [select id, Email, Name from user ] 2) User u1 =[select id, Name,  Manager__r.id  from user where Id  =:u.id]; Basically i am fetching the user manager in the second sql  and then am sending the email alert... it goes upto 4 levels...... like  CEO/VP.... I have a  custom field  on User which is hierachry

Comment: So the CEO/VP has no manager assigned to them? If I ask-business wise, how do you identify that a particular user is the **Bill Gates**? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to query Manager__r field in the first query. 
User  u = [select id,  Manager__r.Id, Email, Name from user LIMIT 10];